# Quiet Birchas Kohanim

Tags: halacha, minhag, birchas-kohanim, machlokes

According to many mainstream authorities, the widespread practice of Ashkenazic Kohanim outside of Israel of refraining from *birchas kohanim* is a *minhag ta'us* and possibly even forbidden biblically as a *bittul aseh* (annulment of a positive commandment).  If an individual kohen wishes to be accommodate these views without causing a conflict with the congregation in which he is praying, are there any problems with his reciting *birchas kohanim* discretely, e.g. quietly, in his place, and omitting the customary hand configuration?

Comment: "possibly even forbidden biblically as a bittul aseh" Source? I don't think anyone thinks it's a bittul aseh. How could that be if no one calls them up to dukhen? Are Kohanim who can't make it to minyan in Israel mevattel an aseh Deorayta? No way

Comment: @DoubleAA I believe the Rambam in his koteres to hilchos tefilla says it is a daily obligation.  So, at the very least, a kohen who has not yet fulfilled his obligation, e.g. at a mincha by shekia, would be potentially committing a bitul aseh.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60647/discussion-on-question-by-loewian-quiet-birchas-kohanim).

Answer (score 3):

It would at least be a waste of time since holding up the arms and reciting the blessing aloud are required (ShA OC 128:14). In any event so long as no one called him up to bless, he isn't violating anything (ibid. :2).

Comment: ayin beer hetiv which sounds like might not be so clear that lchol hadeyos those requirements are l'ikuva b'dieved : http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.128.14?lang=bi&p2=Ba%27er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.128.25&lang2=bi

Comment: (Though MB sounds like you: http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.128.14?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.128.50&lang2=bi )

Comment: (...and http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.128.14?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.128.52&lang2=bi and http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.128.14?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.128.53&lang2=bi)

Comment: From the lashon harambam at least, it's hard to say they're any more meakev than the shem hameforash - since it's from the same derasha - which is omitted when there's such a need - and without eliminating birchas kohanim entirely: http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Prayer_and_the_Priestly_Blessing.14.10?lang=bi&with=Kessef%20Mishneh&lang2=he